# Adding version number to css files

Tags: html, css

I'm still relatively new to making webs, I read about adding version numbers to CSS files so the browser loads the newest version, I changed my style.css name to style.css?v=1 on my HTML, do I need to change the file name of the CSS too? Forgive me if my lingo is weird

Answer (score 0):

As @Dan Canetti suggested - this is the comment that I had above - included as an answer so the OP can resolve the question.

No - you do not need to change the file name of the .css file. The query string that is appended to the file name in the browser is used to allow the sourcing of the file without changing it.

If you have a styles.css and you call it with styles.css?v=1 - then it will still load. The difference is that the browser can cache the content and if it already has loaded styles.css?v=1 then it will load it from the cache - not the server.

Then if you make some change and you then call styles.css?v=2... the v2 version will not be in the loal cache and so the browser will retieve it from the server